# How to convert from File to IFile in java, for files outside the project?

Tags: java, eclipse, workspace

Normally, this code is used for converting from `File` to `IFile`:

```
IWorkspace workspace= ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();    
IPath location= Path.fromOSString(file.getAbsolutePath()); 
IFile ifile= workspace.getRoot().getFileForLocation(location);
```

But this only works for java files within the project. How can I get the `IFile` when `File` file is not in the workspace (not in the project)?

Comment: Did you mean getFileForLocation in line 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed this for using the Binding Resolutions from the Eclipse AST framework. But apparently, this is not possible - for anyone who need it, check this site:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=206391

Answer (score 11):

`IResource` and its child `IFile` were originally meant to be used only for resources located in the workspace. See the [Javadoc for IResource](http://help.eclipse.org/help32/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/resources/IResource.html).

However, since Eclipse 3.3 there is support for external files as well, see [this Eclipse Wiki page](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_open_an_editor_on_a_file_outside_the_workspace%3F).

Comment: I tried this solution but I get this error    

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Workspace is closed.

when I try to get the workspace, like this: 

IWorkspace ws = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();

Can you please help with this problem?

Comment: The Eclipse Wiki link is broken.