# Open .java-file in Standard-Eclipse Java-Editor programmatically from main-method

Tags: java, eclipse, file, editor

How can I open a java-File programmaticaly in the standard java-editor of eclipse. I dont want to use it from a plugin, but from a method. I'm searching something like this:

```
    String absolutePath = "C:\\dummfile.java";
    // Getting Editor from Workbench or something like that
    Editor javaEditor = Workbench.getJavaEditor();
    javaEditor.setInput(absolutePath);
    // show and set focus
    javaEditor.openEditor();
```

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18120285/open-file-in-editor-programmatically-after-renaming) but i can't convert from File to IFile.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To convert `File` to `IFile` :

```
IWorkspace workspace= ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();    
IPath location= Path.fromOSString(file.getAbsolutePath()); 
IFile ifile= workspace.getRoot().getFileForLocation(location);
```

from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960746/how-to-convert-from-file-to-ifile-in-java-for-files-outside-the-project) and [this](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/98045/)

Comment: Yes i've read this threads. But as i said, i dont want to start the Editor from a plugin, so i got the "workspace_closed"-exception. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Workspace is closed.
 at org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace(ResourcesPlugin.java:407)

Comment: @schmusehase : you want to use the eclipse editor but without  using a rcp product ?

Comment: exactly, i want to use the eclipse ide from which i started my program

Answer (score 0):

http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_open_an_editor_programmatically%3F

Did you take a look at this? Since you have the absolute path of the file, the code sample in this link should work for you.